# Moving documentation example to another topic - Error

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-examples

I've added a proposed change examples for `time measurement` in Debugging topic of Javascript language Documentation. link: [Javascript.Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging)

Fellow user pointed out that a similar topic (with only one example) already exists in another topic: [Performance tips](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/1640/performance-tips/13056/elapsed-time#t=201607270918531721709) and suggested to edit it and add my examples. I agreed and tried to move it to that topic.

But in the middle of process for some reason it stuck like this:

[image: screen shot]

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: What I did eventually is manually edit the relevant topic and added two of my examples to existing one. Which of course not the worst solution, but definitely shouldn't be the best. I hope stackoverflow developers will see the error I explained above - and track it down, so for the users the process will be easier.